# Wrong alphabetical ordering by manytomany field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am Django beginner and trying to figure it out why got wrong alphabetical ordering by m2m field when I have more than 2 records.
Below provide dummy information for your better understanding.

Created from scratch `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)
```

After filling db with some data, tried simple query in python console for give all the `publishers` which are ordered by `authors` they have:

```
from app.models import Publisher
[print(i.pub_authors.all()) for i Publisher.all().order_by('pub_authors__name')]
```

Example of output when have only 1 `author` to each `publisher`(correct ordering):

```
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: C>]>
```

Example of output when have more than 1 `author` to each `publisher`(wrong ordering):

```
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>, <Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>, <Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>, <Author: C>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>, <Author: C>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: C>]>
```

Expected results:

```
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>, <Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: A>, <Author: C>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: B>, <Author: C>]>
<QuerySet [<Author: C>]>
```

Hope you can pointed me at right direction, why this could happen at least(can't solve it for a week, very struggling on it)

**Updated:** I provided wrong expected results(sorry), update it. I see that I need to clarify a little:
I am got incorrect order between `Publisher` querysets, not inside each `Publisher`.
So I'm worried when `Publisher` queryset with [A,B] `authors` placed before `Publisher` with [A] `authors`. Or Publisher with [A,C] placed between [B] and [C]

Comment: You here order the publishers by the name of the author, *not* the related queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg` helps here